# How to properly insert an image?

Tags: graphics, floats, layout

This image should have been fit after (a) and it seems like the image can fit into the previous page...I have been facing this kind of problem a lot and I don't know how to fix it.

I tried to use `[h]`, and `[hbt!]` after `\begin{figure}`;

I also tried to decrease width of my image as small as possible and as proper as possible...(i.e. decreasing `\linewidth`)

Is there any better way to do this? Or it's just the way \LaTeX works?

Btw, here is my code for this part:

```
% Code for 6.44
\addtocounter{enumi}{3}
\item \begin{enumerate}
    \item $ \Phi(0.5244005)=0.7000 $\\
    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{644a}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:644a}
    \end{figure}\\
\item 
    $ \Phi(1.644854)=0.9500 $\\
    \begin{figure}[hbt!]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{644b}
        \caption{}
        \label{fig:644b}
    \end{figure}\\
\end{enumerate}
```

[image: My output]

Comment: Your figure surely does not fit the page. So my suggestion is: let it be on the next page by using `[t]`, give a caption to it, and refer to it on the previous page using some labels.

Comment: That is the way how LaTeX works. Apparently for image is not enough space on the page or you have to may images on this page. To say some more specific we need more information about document. The best is in the form of complete small document, which show your problem.

Comment: You are not using a caption for that image. Are you sure you even want it to be a floating `figure`? Floats are supposed to move around when necessary. If you just want to include a graphics exactly where specified in the code, you can remove the whole `figure` environment.

Comment: Try replacing `\includegraphics[width=.4\linewidth]{644a}` with `\includegraphics[height=0.15\textheight]{644a}` and see if the `figure` will fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to try

- setting the heights rather than the widths of the graphs
- placing the graphs side by side, in two separate `minipage` environments within a single `figure` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\bfseries\thesection.\arabic*} % optional
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{6} % just for this example
\begin{enumerate}
\setcounter{enumi}{43}  % just for this example
\item
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item $ \Phi(0.5244005)=0.7000 $
    \item $ \Phi(1.644854)=0.9500 $    
    \captionsetup{skip=0.25\baselineskip} % default is '1\baselineskip'
    \begin{figure}[hb!]
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[height=0.15\textheight]{644a} % set height rather than width
        \caption{$ \Phi(0.5244005)=0.7000 $}
        \label{fig:644a}
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[height=0.15\textheight]{644b}
        \caption{$ \Phi(1.644854)=0.9500 $}
        \label{fig:644b}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```